# Sympy nonlinsolve gives incorrect answer

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to solve a system of two equations in Sympy. I've chosen numbers that I've solved for on paper, so I know what the result should be.

```
# Ramp down then up.

a, v_s, v_e, t_m, t_e, d_e = sp.symbols("a, v_s, v_e, t_m, t_e, d_e")

v_s = 15
v_e = 20
a = 1
d_e = 212.5

v_m = v_s - t_m * a

Eq1 = v_m + a * (t_e - t_m) - v_e
Eq2 = t_e * v_m + (v_s - v_m) * t_m / 2 + (v_e - v_m) * (t_e - t_m) / 2 - d_e

sp.nonlinsolve([Eq1, Eq2], [t_m, t_e])
```

This is giving me `t_m=(5, 15), t_e=(25, 55)`. The particular answer I'm looking for is `t_m=5` and `t_e=15`. To validate this, I copy pasted Eq1 and Eq2 into Desmos (a calculator) and they do not resolve to zero as expected when I plug in Sympy's solution, but they do when I plug in my solution.

Is this an issue with Sympy or an issue with my brain?

#### Background

Basically this is a velcoity profile. Start at `v_s`, and end at `v_e`. The goal is to ramp down as much as possible to `v_m` such that `v_m` < `v_s`, then ramp up to v_e so that the whole thing takes place before traversing a distance `d_e`. I'm trying to solve for the time that this takes `t_e`.

The velocity profile looks something like this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I just misread the output.

I was reading it as `t_m=(5, 15), t_e=(25, 55)` when in reality it was `(t_m=5, t_e=15), (t_m=25, t_e=55)`.

Hope this helps someone else one day!